# Multiply matrices in high dimensional space

Tags: arrays, matlab

We have for example these matrices:

```
M = rand(30,45,4);
U = rand(4,4);
```

1. In first step I want to multiply each element of the matrix `M`, which is a 4 element vector, with the `U` matrix. This will result in in a new `M1` matrix whose elements are also `1x4`. For example, `M1(1,1,:) = M(1,1,:)*U;` This in matrix dimensions, for the specific example, corresponds in `1x4 = (1x4)(4x4)`. The whole `M1` matrix has the same dimensions as `M`.
2. In second step, the `M1` must be multiplied with the `M'` in the same way and obtain the final `F` matrix which is a 2D matrix with 1D elements. For example, `F(1,1) = M1(1,1,:)*M(1,1,:)';`

In other words, each element of the `F` matrix is [image] where [image] is each of the `1x4` elements of the `M` matrix.

**Attached example:**

```
M = rand(600, 800, 4);
U = rand(4,4);
F = nan(size(M,1),size(M,2));
for i=1:size(M,1)*size(M,2)
    [r,c]=ind2sub(size(M),i);
    F(i) = squeeze(M(r,c,:))'*U*squeeze(M(r,c,:)); 
end
```

`Elapsed time is 58.627296 seconds.`

**@Luis Mendo answer:**

```
tic
Mr = reshape(M, [], size(M,3));
result = reshape(sum(Mr*U.*Mr,2), size(M,1), size(M,2));
toc
```

`Elapsed time is 0.062898 seconds.`

Could you please somebody suggest a way without using for loops?

Thank you for you time!

**PS:** *Matlab 2013a 64x, Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU 2.40 GHz, 4GB memory*

Comment: Why "without using for loops"?

Comment: Please clarify. What are `N` and `M'`? Which of the multiplications are matrix multiplications and which are element-wise?

Comment: M' is probably the transposed of M

Comment: Without loops because with them is slow. `M` is the matrix and `N` is 
the dimension of each `M` matrix element. `M'` is the transpose `M` matrix.

Comment: How do you "transpose" a 4D array? Only the first two dimensions, maybe??

Comment: What's the size of final result?

Comment: How do you define M1 * M', exactly? It's not standard matrix multiplication

Comment: I made some changes in my question I hope that clarifies:)

Comment: That for loops are slow is only valid for quite old versions of matlab (me thinks 2008 or earlier). I think you should focus on why it is slow - maybe you can find a quick optimization.

Comment: Please provide a sample input and output

Comment: First of all thank you very much of your interest and I would like to express my apologies for the unclear question. I have made some changes please take a look and if are satisfied please rise the hold on.

Comment: @Full Decent, Example attached:)

Comment: @Thoth I think the question is clearer now. I've voted to reopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understood correctly, but maybe this is what you want:

```
Mr = reshape(M, [], size(M,4));
result = reshape(sum(Mr*U.*Mr,2), size(M,1), size(M,2));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers but I have not tested yet because I have made some changes in the question to make it more clear. Is it possible to give an acceptance?

Comment: __@Luis Mendo__ it worked I just change `size(M,4)` to `size(M,3)` this was because my question was unclear. Thank you very much!